# Class cast exception in scala play

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.5

I am trying use the play.api.Configuration object to get rid of the deprecation warnings

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy
import play.api.Play.current
import play.libs.Akka

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import play.api.Configuration
import javax.inject.Inject

object TestClient {

  val config = new Configuration(_)

 private val nodes = config.asInstanceOf[Configuration].getStringList("Test_ENDPOINT").map(_.asScala.toList).getOrElse(List("127.0.0.1"))

}
```

when  I run my application I get the error

```
Caused by:  java.lang.ClassCastException: utils.TestClient$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast to play.api.Configuration
```

I cannot convert this object to class due to chain dependencies. Below is the full trace:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:184)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at Global$.onStart(Global.scala:10)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:111)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:102)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:102)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:102)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:171)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: utils.TestClient$$anonfun$1 cannot be cast to play.api.Configuration
    at utils.TestClient$.<init>(TestClient.scala:17)
    at utils.TestClient$.<clinit>(TestClient.scala)
    at Global$.onStart(Global.scala:10)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:111)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:102)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:102)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:102)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:171)
```

Also tried using configuration load but not working.

```
val config = Configuration.load()
```

Multiple markers at this line:

```
overloaded method value load with alternatives: (environment: play.api.Environment)play.api.Configuration <and> (environment: play.api.Environment,devSettings: Map[String,AnyRef])play.api.Configuration cannot be applied to ()
overloaded method value load with alternatives: (environment: play.api.Environment)play.api.Configuration <and> (environment: play.api.Environment,devSettings: Map[String,AnyRef])play.api.Configuration cannot be applied to ()
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you somehow. http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-open-read-files-scala-examples

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a illustration of what you are doing:

```
scala> class Example(s:String)
defined class Example

scala> val  c = new Config(_) 
c: String => Example = <function1>

scala> c.asInstanceOf[Example]
java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to Example
  ... 42 elided
```

You are trying to cast a function `Config => Configuration` into a Configuration.

Looking at [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration$) you will find multiple alternative to get a Configuration instance.

`Configuration.empty` might be a start.